# umbraco project in VS2012 - how?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, umbraco

Now it's my turn to ask this question..

I've been reading about setting up an umbraco project in VS2012 but i really don't know if im doing it worng, or if it's just not possible..

Is it possible to setup an umbraco project in VS2012 with ability to add templates, and documenttypes and create sites and more with VS2012 without using the umbraco admin tool? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in fact, only 2 minutes ago I finished checking in a brand new project, a VS2012 solution housing an Umbraco v6 website.

My solution/directory setup is particular, and no doubt yours is too, but the bottom line is that the Umbraco is just an ASP.NET website, so you can add it to a solution using thew "Add existing website" option, to the root or subdirectory of your will.

Then you can use the Solution Explorer to edit files such as those in the `css`, `masterPages`, and `macroScripts` folder etc.

One note of caution would be this. When using 'Umbraco scripts' (i.e. Razor scripting files and such) then, when created in the Umbraco UI, a calling Macro is also created (by default, though there is an opt-out) and (historically) some database goings-on, and so in the case of scripts, I think it's always wise to initially create them using the Umbraco UI.

Other than that, are you having a specific problem, as I don't see you point one out?

Comment: hm yeah i was just looking for a mabye step by step guide on how to do this.. but i can try to open my alredy exsisting project in VS2012.. and see how it runs

Comment: yeah but it seems like ive sovled my "problem" now.. it works great, so thanks!